# Joins tables in Cakephp

Tags: cakephp

i have a two tables namely; histories and users. i need to display data like:

---

### id  | Username |  Lastest created Post |  First created Post

the data of id and username is from users table and the last created and first created post data is from histories. i need to view all the users, their lastest created post and their first created post. please help me to make controller and view thanks

Comment: both tables are related to each other with foreign key.? associations are defined in model.

Answer (score 0):

Try below.

```
<?php
    $users = $this->User->find('all',array
    (
        'conditions' => array
        (
            //conditions goes here
        ),
        'fields' => array
        (
            'User.id',
            'User.username',
            'History.Lastest created Post',
            'History.First created Post'
        )
    ));
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assume that relation between 'User' and 'History' table is One-to-One and there's a 'user_id' column in **History** table, you may need to specify relation between them in **History** model, for example:

```
   var $hasOne = array(
     'User' => array(
            'className' => 'User',
            'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => ''
       )
    );
```

Then, you need to perform `joins` to do this. For example, somewhere in your **User** model, try something like this:

```
 class User extends AppModel {    

        ....  

       function getAllUsersHistory{

             $allHistories = $this->find('all', array(
                'joins' => array(
                    'table' => 'history',
                    'alias' => 'HistoryJoin'
                    'type' => 'INNER',
                    'conditions' => array(
                        // your conditions, for example: 'History.user_id' => 'User.id'
                    )
                ),  
                'fields' => array(
                    'User.id', 
                    'User.username', 
                    'History.lastest_created_post', 
                    'History.first_created_post'
                )           
             ));   

          return $allHistories; 

         }

         .....

    }
```